# k closest point to origin

Tags: python, max-heap

I am trying to solve this problem. https://leetcode.com/problems/k-closest-points-to-origin/ I have used maxheap and following is my code. This works well for points= [[1,3],[-2,2]], k = 1. However for points = [[3,3],[5,-1],[-2,4]], k = 2, this is giving the output as [[3,3],[5,-1]] whereas the expected output is [[3,3],[-2,4]]. I am not being able to figure out why my code is picking the point [5,-1]. Please help find the mistake I am doing.

```
from heapq import *
class Solution:

def kClosest(self, points: List[List[int]], k: int) -> List[List[int]]:

    maxHeap = []
    for i in range(k):
        heappush(maxHeap, points[i])
        
    for i in range(k, len(points)):
        dist = self.distance(points[i])
        heapdistance_from_origin = self.distance(maxHeap[0])
        if dist < heapdistance_from_origin:
            heappop(maxHeap)
            heappush(maxHeap, points[i])
    return maxHeap

def distance(self, point: List[int]):
     return point[0] * point[0] + point[1] * point[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:** `heappush` and `heappop` don't order the heap elements by distance to origin. They use the natural order of the elements instead (they're lists, so it's lexicographical order). So `maxHeap[0]` is usually *not* the point furthest from the origin.

**You can use `heapq.nsmallest`**, that supports a `key` argument (and it uses almost the same algorithm you do):

```
    def kClosest(self, points: List[List[int]], k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        return nsmallest(k, points, key=lambda p: hypot(*p))
```

Or:

```
    def kClosest(self, points: List[List[int]], k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
        return nsmallest(k, points, key=partial(dist, (0, 0)))
```

Btw no need to import it yourself, LeetCode imports pretty much everything for you already. (Of course you can still do it if you want for clarity or so, then in my case it would be clear that `hypot` and `dist` come from `math` and that `partial` comes from `functools`. LeetCode is supposed to be about coding interviews, and I guess in a whiteboard interview, it's convenient to just say out loud "partial from functools" and have less to write, maybe that's why LeetCode does this.)

**If you want to implement it yourself:** Instead of making your heap hold bare points, you could make it hold pairs of `(negated_distance, point)`. Negated because `heapq` implements a min-heap, so if you want a max-heap, negate the values. Here's that:

```
    def kClosest(self, points: List[List[int]], k: int) -> List[List[int]]:

        maxHeap = []
        for p in points[:k]:
            heappush(maxHeap, (-self.distance(p), p))

        for p in points[k:]:
            dist = self.distance(p)
            heapdistance_from_origin = -maxHeap[0][0]
            if dist < heapdistance_from_origin:
                heappop(maxHeap)
                heappush(maxHeap, (-dist, p))
        return [p for _, p in maxHeap]
```

Or you could convert the points to instances of a `Point` class that does the comparison you want:

```
    def kClosest(self, points: List[List[int]], k: int) -> List[List[int]]:

        class Point(list):
            def __lt__(self_, other):
                return self.distance(self_) > self.distance(other)
        points = list(map(Point, points))
        
        maxHeap = []
        for i in range(k):
            heappush(maxHeap, points[i])

        for i in range(k, len(points)):
            dist = self.distance(points[i])
            heapdistance_from_origin = self.distance(maxHeap[0])
            if dist < heapdistance_from_origin:
                heappop(maxHeap)
                heappush(maxHeap, points[i])
        return maxHeap
```

Comment: could you please explain:  return [p for _, p in maxHeap] and thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: @pari That's just a *list comprehension* extracting the bare points from the `(value, point)` pairs on the heap.